# Jquery - Adicionar elemento a cada determinada quantidade de outros elementos

Tags: jquery, for, append, quebras-de-linha, elementos

Preciso adicionar uma `tag` de quebra (`<br>` ou `<hr>`) a cada quantidade de `<div>` que surge dinamicamente.

Por `PHP`, eu agrupo 10 registros por `<div>`, ou seja, a cada 10 registros cria-se uma `<div>` para começar a coletar os novos resultados, assim:

```
<div class="grupo">
    <?php foreach($qr->result() as $key => $resultado){
        if ($key % 10 === 0) {
            echo "</div><div class=\"grupo\">";
        } 
    }// foreach ?>
</div>
<!--/.grupo-->
```

Então, após 3 `<div class="grupo">` criadas, deve-se inserir a quebra (`<br>` ou `<hr>`).

Por PHP não consigo, por isso estou tentando por Jquery. Acredito que seja com `for`, `appendTo` e qualquer outra coisa que não tenho nem ideia do que é nem como faze-lo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com jQuery, percorrendo os elementos da classe `.grupos`, você pode adicionar um `<hr>` sempre após o terceiro elemento usando `.each()`:

```
$(function(){

   $(".grupo").each(function(i){

      // "i" é o índice dos elementos na coleção
      // como começa com 0, soma +1 para iniciar de 1 a contagem
      var c = i+1;

      // a cada grupo de 3, adiciona um "hr" após
      if(c % 3 == 0) $(this).after("<hr>");

    });

});
```